# How to correctly identify bearing cones for axles, to find replacements?

Tags: replacement, axle, cones

The cones of a bicycle front axle are quite pitted, and I decided to replace them. The Axle still is fine, I'd only need to replace the cones.

The problem I'm having is finding replacement cones. I'm not sure what sort of data I need to search for them.

So far I tried with the axle diameter (9.5mm or "Fg9.5", when measured on the thread), the length (11.75mm) and the OD (15.5mm) of the cone. The cone wrench needed for those cones is 12mm, I also tried searching using that, but I'm having very little luck. It seems most shops selling cones (including sellers on Ebay) refer to the bicycle brand or model name. However, the bicycle in question is an old, German ladies bike, around 20 years old.
I can't find any markings on the cones, and cones don't seem to be sold for a particular axle type (mine's a Fg9.5 x 136mm, but that one is nearly impossible to find).

I'm not sure I'm using the right combination of data to look for them, or I'm looking completely in the wrong way. Since cones are one of parts that wear quite quickly, I'd imagine there must be replacements but I'm having a really hard time to find them.

Comment: _Fg 9.5_ is an old metric fine thread used only on bikes. It means either _Fahrradgewinde_ or _Feingewinde_.

Comment: @gschenk yeah, that much I've figured out. Getting a replacement axle for another bike as an entire set with bearings and cones was easier than getting cones for this one.

Answer (score 1):

I find it rather difficult to get cones by themselves in Germany. It is much easier to get an entire replacement axle with cones. Often enough I found the whole assembly to cost less than an individual identical cone.

The good thing about cup-and-cone hub bearings is that there are only two ball sizes. The front always has 4,762 mm (3/16 inch) balls. That means also the races on the cones will fit.

When the outer diametre fits as well and the cones have about the same length a different axle with their cones might do.

Comment: I was considering this, too, but I also have dust caps that need to fit into the hub, while also fit around the cones. The other option would be to replace the entire hub, meaning putting new spokes in and everything, and that I think is a bit *much* for just replacing two cones...

Comment: Assuming I'd buy an entire new axle, what should I be looking for? Fg9.5, or 3/8", with the appropriate length?